# How can I upload image with form data?

Tags: react-native, expo

I am learning React Native with Expo. For a test project, I have a screen named "Create profile" where I am trying to add the image selected on the Expo image picker with other text inputs - location, description. How do I combined the inputs along with the image from the image picker?

My current guess is to use base64 for the image or set the image input as "this.state.image" to call the image:uri from the picker. Though I may be going the wrong way with this. Also another option is to use Content-Type:multipart-form/data though when tried it doesn't post any data to the API call.

The API is built on a Django app using Django Rest Framework.

My Code is below: 
        render() {
    let { image } = this.state;

```
function handleSubmit(props) {
  fetch('<API URL HERE>', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }, 
    body:JSON.stringify({
      'location': this.state.location,
      'description': this.state.description,
      //user image field and input below
      'user_image':this.state.image


    })
  });
}
```

## Image picker

```
_pickImage = async () => {
try {
  let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
    mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
    allowsEditing: true,
    aspect: [4, 3],
    quality: 1,
  });
  if (!result.cancelled) {
    const image = result.uri;
    this.setState({ image: result.uri });
  }

  console.log(result);
} catch (E) {
  console.log(E);
}
```

};

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just managed to figure this out and for the benefit of others who want a similar result, I've posted it here.

1. For the image picker you need to add other variables such as the image uri, filename, and file type.

   ```
     _pickImage = async () => {
      try {
      let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
        mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
   allowsEditing: true,
   aspect: [4, 3],
   quality: 1,
      });
        if (!result.cancelled) {
   this.setState({ image: result.uri });

   let localUri = result.uri;
   let filename = localUri.split('/').pop();

   // Infer the type of the image
   let match = /\.(\w+)$/.exec(filename);
   let type = match ? `image/${match[1]}` : `image`;

   this.setState({ localUri: result.uri });
   this.setState({ filename: filename });
   this.setState({ type: type });

     }
   ```

Then for the form data, you'll have to adjust the image field to include those variables when submitting them along with the other fields.

```
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('location',this.state.location);
    formData.append('description',this.state.description);
    formData.append('member_unique','IEQ'); 
    formData.append('user_image', {type:type, uri:uri, name:filename});

 function handleSubmit(props) {
  fetch('<posting api>', {
    method: 'POST',
    body:formData, 

  });
}
```

Comment: It looks like you are passing URI string in user_image object, how the server will get the actual file(image/video) to upload it?

Comment: @Furquan FormData or fetch seems to know how to do that if the uri is a "file system uri". But on Android that is not always the case and you get a ContentProvider uri which can't be read by FormData / fetch.

Answer (score 1):

You can create `FormData()` object and append your inputs to this form.

In Photo, You Should pass `URI`of image that you received after selecting image.

You also need to pass `name` and `type` parameter in order to get in Django.

Use header `multipart/form-data` with `POST` request.

You may require `CSRF TOKEN` to send `POST` request to Django

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append("detectImg", {
    uri: image.uri,
    name: "image",
    type: "image/jpg",
});
const response = await fetch("BACKEND_URL", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
         "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
    },
    body: formData,
});
```

Comment: Ferin, your answer did help though. I've made some adjustments and additions to it and it works now. Thank you.